# Placeholder for Multiple Select on mobile (iOS) stays selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, select

Im working on a multiselect select, to be displayed on a mobile device.

This example is on iOS.

```
 <select id="statesLic" multiple="multiple">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Licensed States</option>
  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
...
...
...
```

The placeholder shows correctly, but if a user selects any values, the count will always be one too many, since the placeholder is 'selected' as well. (ex. If Alabama is selected, it will display '2 Selected')

This is not a problem on a single-select, since the placeholder gets deselected.

I know there has to be a simple solution to this, but Im not getting it. (jquery change?)

Alternatively, is there a better way to show a default value on the iPhone, without it counting as selected?

---

Im using Select2 for the desktop, but found it full of issues on mobile. So, on mobile im just using the default behavior (the wheel) with some css styling.

This gets me close:

```
  $('select').on('change', function(event) {
                $('#' +  event.currentTarget.id + ' option[disabled]').remove();
            })
```

But now I need to remove the Placeholders on page load, if the user had previously saved selections (because the count is still off).

Comment: I wonder it making the Licensed State an optgroup instead would work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: Assuming you are using bootstrap multiselect. Any reason you are not configuring the options for: nonSelectedText and other variable selected texts options?

Comment: updated question - I am using select2 on the <select/> tags, but it was clunky on iOS.  So I just went with default behavior on mobile.  Mobile has been secondary to the desktop application for the moment, but I would like to look into jQuery Mobile, etc when I get more time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, using chosen.js for desktop, however by default mobile phones don't load chosen. Here's the solution I ended up using:

```
var isMobile = <I set this boolean from the backend>;

var $selects = $('<your selects selector here>');
if (isMobile) {
  // This is necessary because mobile phones don't load chosen;
  $selects.each(function () {
    $(this).once('setMobilePlaceholder', function () {
      // This will determine if the placeholder is selected after a search
      var selectedTxt = "";
      if ($(':selected', this).length == 0) {
        selectedTxt = " selected";
      }
      $(this)
        .find('option:first-child')
        .before('<option value="" default disabled' + selectedTxt + '>' + $(this).attr('data-placeholder') + '</option>');
      $(this).one('mousedown', function () {
        $(this).find('option:first-child').prop("selected", false);
      });
    });
  });
}
else {
  if ($selects.length > 0) {
    $selects.chosen({
      <chosen options go here>
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this saves someone some time.